# Does Exoplayer supports playing videos via POST METHOD?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I have an API to retrieve videos from our server, the API use the POST method and needs Authorization for Headers and deviceInfo for body parameter.

example.

URL: https://myapi.com/api/pretty_video.mp4 
BODY: deviceInfo = device info 
HEADER: Authorization: Bearer "Token" 
METHOD: POST

I can't find any example of **ExoPlayer** using POST method in playing videos from URL.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I solved it by using OkHttp.

```
DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(new OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
              @Override
              public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                MediaType CONTENT_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(CONTENT_TYPE,"deviceinfo=12345");

                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .post(requestBody) .  // HERE IS THE KEY
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
              }
            })
            .build(), Util.getUserAgent(context,context.getString(R.string.app_name)), defaultBandwidthMeter);
```